# How to get output information with official nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I want to parse the files in /sys/class/drm (edid, modes, status) to obtain some information about the connected monitors. Unfortuantely the nvidia driver does not support DRM. Is there any way to get reliable information about the outputs when using a nvidia driver?

xrandr is no option since it is not reliable since Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the nvidia-smi utility.

You can also use: nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info to list GPU information and connected devices.